# JPA, MySQL and GlassFish crud error

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, glassfish-4

I am using JPA, MySQL and GlassFish in a simple java web servlet netbeans project. It is possible to access (login) but list, edit, destroy and create doesn´t work...

```
"org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.ClassCastException: model.Person cannot be cast to model.Person"
```

and sometimes nothing work!

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: This web container has not yet been started
```

https://www.dropbox.com/s/isazdnwizxth3lt/WebApplication2.zip?dl=0

Comment: Full project at dropbox link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. Must implement transaction `em.getTransaction.begin()` and `.commit()`.
And restart GlassFish server!!